# Как строку 277.00 сконвертировать в число?

Tags: c#, .net

Делал конвертацию сперва в double. Но говорит, что строка имеет неверный формат.

```
string text = "277.00";
double x= Convert.ToDouble(text); // выдает ошибку
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что разделители дробной части бывают разные

`double x= Convert.ToDouble(text,`[`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)`);`

Comment: а в int конвертировать как?

Comment: int y= Convert.ToInt32(x);